# "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed" when searching Realm's ObservedResults

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, realm

With the snippet of code below, I get the following log (Fault) at each keystroke in the search field:

`Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.`

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

class User: Object, Identifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedResults(User.self) var users
    @State private var filter = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(users) { user in
                    Text(user.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Users")
            .searchable(text: $filter, collection: $users, keyPath: \.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or could this be a bug in RealmSwift?

Versions:

- iOS 17.0
- Xcode 15.0
- RealmSwift 10.45.2

Comment: you probably are directly modifying the users datasource in your view inside `.searchable(text: $filter, collection: $users, keyPath: \.name)` modifier , try to move the searching/filtering logic to a view model

Comment: @TejaNandamuri this is all there is, I created a small project to reproduce it in a simple setup. Which logic should I move?

Comment: Looking at the documentation it seems the searchable modifier takes a closure where you handle the search results